# Can't find NSXMLDocument class for XML parsing using NSXML Parser

Tags: ios, ipad, xml-parsing, nsxmlparser, nsxmldocument

I have been trying to trying to parse an xml file using NSXML parser . In that i want to use NSXMLDocument class for storing data in it's instance. After searching in all possible ways i failed to get clear idea about NSXMLDocument. I didn't import any class especially for that. Do i have to add any classes or lib files ???

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`NSXMLDocument`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSXMLDocument_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is not availble on iOS. You options are to use either [`NSXMLParser`](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html) sax based parsing or a third party library.

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply. Could you differentiate SAX & DOM by their functionality simply ? I am trying to convert a project ie. been using TouchXML to NSXMLParser. I wanted to know is there any problem in trying this ?????