# Use of Unresolve identifier NSXMLDocument swift

Tags: ios, iphone, xml, swift2

I need to create XML document from Dictionary ([string : AnyObject]) in iPhone app. Found `NSXMLDocument` class, but it come up with above error even after `Import Foundation`. Restarted whole app and mac but no luck.

How do I create XML File from Dictionary ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21157051/cant-find-nsxmldocument-class-for-xml-parsing-using-nsxml-parser

Comment: Can suggest third party library or how to use NSXMLParser to create XML Doc Please?